# filling array from another array

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I am writing a code and the following message keeps popping up:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at age.TokenizeNumbers.setYears(TokenizeNumbers.java:30)
    at age.AgeNo.main(AgeNo.java:18)
```

the first one on line 30 is giving me a hard time. I'm trying to fill an array1[] (years) with content of array2[] (dates), and I only want the first two digits of the numbers stored in array2[]. There is something wrong with that simple for() loop. as long as I write 
years=dates it returns array1[] (years) just fine. as soon I try for loop, i get an error.
here's the code. thanks
Juraj

```
package age;

import java.io.IOException;

public class TokenizeNumbers {
        int lines;
        long[] dates;
        long[] years;
        long[] dateNum;
        long[] convertedYears;
        long annum = 100000000;

    public TokenizeNumbers() throws IOException{
        String[] dates;
        String[] years;

        Vek v = new Vek("C:\\Users\\Juraj\\workspace\\Mackin\\src\\age\\rc.txt");
        lines = v.readLines();
        long[] dateNum = v.openFile();

    }

    public long[] getDateArray(long[] dateNum){
        dates = dateNum;
        return dates;
    }

    public long[] setYears(){
        for(int k = 0; k<dates.length; k++){    
        years[k]=dates[k]/annum;
        }
        return years;
    }


    public void printYears(){
        int y;

        for(y=0; y<lines; y++){
            System.out.println(years[y]);

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nowhere in your code does it show your `years` array being initialized. There are multiple other problems with your code.

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
years[k] = dates[k]/annum;
```

you are attempting to assign values to `years[k]` but `years` is not initialized in the code provided. You could do

```
long[] years = new long[SIZE];
```

The same applys to `dateNum`.

Also you have `String` arrays `dates` and `years` in your constructor of `TokenizeNumbers` although are not used could lead to confusion.

Have a look at [Arrays#copyOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28long%5B%5D,%20int%29) for copying arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with `dates.length` in you code:

```
public long[] setYears(){
     for(int k = 0; k<dates.length; k++){    
        years[k]=dates[k]/annum;
     }
     return years;
}
```

You must be using `dates.length` before setting(initializing) it. So when you perform `dates.length`, it says `NPE`, so make sure you initialize `dates` before using it.

Answer (score 0):

date[] and year[]

aren't initialized , you need to initialize them with " new " keyword